# Not able to run version one xUnit.net tests using console runner in xUnit.net v2

Tags: unit-testing, xunit.net, xunit2

In my project we are upgrading to xUnit 2. As a result, we upgraded the console runner also which is used to run tests on build server.

We did not upgrade the exsting test projects to use xUnit 2. They are still referring to xUnit.1.9.2.

As per the [documentation](https://xunit.github.io/docs/running-tests-in-parallel.html) it should work.

> The console runner in xUnit.net v2 is capable of running unit tests from both xUnit.net v1 and v2.

However we see errors.

```
xUnit.net Console Runner (32-bit .NET 4.0.30319.18444)
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'xunit.abstractions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8d05b1bb7a6fdb6c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

These are the list of files I have copied from the package folder of the xunit.runner.console.2.1.0 and kept into the build server folder. I invoke **xunit.console.x86.exe** in my scripts with required parameters.

```
HTML.xslt
NUnitXml.xslt
xunit.abstractions.dll
xunit.console.exe
xunit.console.exe.config
xunit.console.x86.exe
xunit.console.x86.exe.config
xunit.runner.reporters.desktop.dll
xunit.runner.utility.desktop.dll
xUnit1.xslt
```

Comment: Wild guess: Are the files Unblocked? Either way, the Fusion Log Viewer should have the answer (or attach a debugger and look at the inner exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake. The project was referencing another project which had the xunit upgraded to version 2. As a result "xunit.execution.desktop.dll" got pulled into the debug folder which led to the problem.